# html refreshing issue in widows phone 8 when entering the form

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

Iam displaying a form inside the bootstrap modal dialog. But, the elements disappears/flickers when scrolling the form keeping keypad open in windows phone 8. This issue is not observed in any other browsers. e.g. firefox, iOS, mac etc... It would be great if someone helps me to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

Some time cross browsers effects some tags and scripts, may be you are using a kind of browser where html5 is not supported for html5 support even in IE you can use **HTML5.JS** here is the [`LINK`](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) For reference see this [`Link`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/make-html5-elements-work-in-old-ie/)